# Font difference in Mac and Windows on website

Tags: css, fonts, font-face, webfonts, line-height

I've been facing font line-height issue in either one of Windows or Mac. The position of the font(text) in Windows and Mac acts differently.

Font -> Brasley (16px)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Font Brasley acts differently in Mac and Windows because of the default configuration in line-height. If the total line-height is 3 and split 1 each from top to bottom, then the text is displayed like below.

Mac -> left

Windows -> right

[image: Font]

**Solution:** Use [Web Safe Fonts](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_websafe_fonts.asp) (Ex: font-sans, Helvetica, etc..) to solve this issue.